I have a syntax error and I can't get why
SELECT c.LocationNum, c.OwnerNum, o.FirstName, o.LastName
FROM CondoUnit c
JOIN Owner o
ON c.OwnerNum=o.OwnerNum; 

Expected to see for every condo locationnum, ownernum, firstname, last name. Access says it is a syntax error

Please tag or mention exactly which SQL syntax this is.

Not to familiar with the access sql dialect. But what happens if you leave out the 'c' and '0' and use the table names instead?
Furter more... doesn't access give a hint on what is going on? Just the mention of a syntax error?

I think you're missing the AS for the table aliases... FROM CondoUnit AS c JOIN Owner AS o - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/access-sql-from-clause-2a7d031c-6912-4e8c-a644-590940ddaed1#bm2

can you also check just by selecting the columns on their own i.e without joining and check if the table name and each column name is the expected one?

@phuzi No. MS-Access also support alias without keyword As. Problem is in join type not defined. In access there are only three join type ` (1) Inner Join (2) Left Join (3) Right Join. So, OP must specify join type.

The Access database engine does not accept JOIN alone and complains "Syntax Error in FROM clause" when encountering it.  You must always specify the type of join you want (INNER, LEFT, or RIGHT).
I think you want INNER JOIN:
SELECT c.LocationNum, c.OwnerNum, o.FirstName, o.LastName
FROM CondoUnit c
INNER JOIN Owner o
ON c.OwnerNum=o.OwnerNum;

